# Is there an equivalent to Boost::Python for Java?

Tags: java, python, boost

I've been working with Boost::Python to expose some high-performance code to python recently, and it's just a dream to work with.  I'd like to be able to maintain a single C++ codebase and expose it to Python via Boost, and to Java as well.  I know about JNI, but I was wondering if there's something equivalent to Boost::Python, but targeting Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of Java projects that let you call functions exposed in DLLs without writing JNI wrapper code. These include [J/Invoke](http://www.jinvoke.com/), [NativeCall](http://johannburkard.de/software/nativecall/), [xFunction](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/xfunction.html), [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/), and others.

Comment: Have you used them?  Have a personal preference?

Comment: I haven't; sorry. I've done a bit of JNI, and found it bearable.

Answer (score 1):

I think [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) can also be a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is [javacpp](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp). I never used it myself, but it seems a better fit than JNA to my C++ code base.